# Error while GARCH Modeling using Python

Tags: python, numpy, model, scipy

I have a sample python code for GARCH modeling which creates a data of randomly generated numbers. I want to replace the numbers with my own csv file which contains a column vector, but that just doesn't work.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

r=np.array([0.945532630498276,
0.614772790142383,
0.834417758890680,
0.862344782601800,
0.555858715401929,
0.641058419842652,
0.720118656981704,
0.643948007732270,
0.138790608092353,
0.279264178231250,
0.993836948076485,
0.531967023876420,
0.964455754192395,
0.873171802181126,
0.937828816793698])

print r

f=open('main_ax.csv')
b=f.read()
r=np.array(b)
print r
def GARCH11_logL(param, r):
    omega, alpha, beta = param
    n = len(r)
    s = np.ones(n)
    for i in range(3,n):
        s[i] = omega + alpha*r[i-1]**2 + beta*(s[i-1]) # GARCH(1,1) model
    logL = -( (-np.log(s) - r**2/s).sum() )            # calculate the sum 
    return logL
R = optimize.fmin(GARCH11_logL,np.array([.1,.1,.1]),args=(r,),full_output=1)
print R
print
print("omega = %.6f\nbeta  = %.6f\nalpha = %.6f\n") % (R[0][0],R[0][2],R[0][1])
```

This program throws me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gaurav\Desktop\Ram\garch_model.py", line 35, in <module>
    R = optimize.fmin(GARCH11_logL,np.array([.1,.1,.1]),args=(r,),full_output=1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 377, in fmin
    res = _minimize_neldermead(func, x0, args, callback=callback, **opts)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 435, in _minimize_neldermead
    fsim[0] = func(x0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 285, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
  File "C:\Users\Gaurav\Desktop\Ram\garch_model.py", line 32, in GARCH11_logL
    s[i] = omega + alpha*r[i-1]**2 + beta*(s[i-1]) # GARCH(1,1) model
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'numpy.string_' and 'int'
```

Any help to fix this code will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines

```
f=open('main_ax.csv')
b=f.read()
r=np.array(b)
```

create an array with a single element that is a string.  You haven't converted the contents of the file into an array of numbers.

You can replace that code with a call to [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html):

```
r = np.loadtxt('main_ax.csv')
```